# Нужно вывести на экран терминала убунту полное имя текущего каталога

Tags: c++, ubuntu, консоль

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t seconds = time(NULL);
    tm* timeinfo = localtime(&seconds);
    cout << asctime(timeinfo) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Нужно вывести на экран терминала убунту текущую дату и время, полное имя текущего каталога, полное имя домашнего каталога пользователя, имя пользователя, собственное имя программы
Время я вывел, остальное под вопросом

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu:

- Полное имя текущего каталога *(то-есть абсолютный путь?)*: `system("pwd")`
- Полное имя домашнего каталога: `system("pwd ~")`
- Имя пользователя: `system("whoami")`
- Собственное имя программы... `cout << "App name"`?

Comment: не получается, к сожалению, опубликовал ошибки, которые выводятся

Comment: @nedoprog [почитайте](http://cppstudio.com/post/883/)

Comment: огромное спасибо! получилось